# Devise Integration Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am having some trouble with my integration tests using devise. It is like it doesn't `sign_in` despite the method running fine.

```
require 'admin_test_helper'

class Admin::PagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    sign_in users(:one), scope: :admin
    @page = pages(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get admin_pages_url
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

**Test Helper**

```
# test/admin_test_helper.rb
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
  fixtures :all

  setup do
    @organization = organizations(:one)
  end
end
```

One thing I noticed when I added a breakpoint in the setup and tried the sign_in method. It returned a proc. Not sure if it should be returning something else?

My test will fail with `Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <302: Found> redirect to <http://www.example.com/users/sign_in>`

I do not have confirmable on which I have noticed as the problem in other posts.

Comment: It's redirecting to the sign in page. You should verify that you're actually signing in as an admin and that it succeeds.

Comment: Thanks @dty any idea how to do that? I have tried checking current_user but it returns nil

Comment: Followup. sign_in does appear to be working, just not setting current_user which I use in my controller to validate. Any idea why it wouldn't set a current_user?

Comment: Seems like I may have had another problem with cancancan abilities. Hopefully have solved. Thanks for the help @dty